# quantmod overriding the warning message

Tags: r, quantmod

Been trying to use quantmod to analyze a large amount of stocks using loops. Problem is I don't know if yahoo has all the stock data I need so I was trying to program R to skip over the errors when it fails to download but I can't seem to turn off the warning message. After the usual library start up I do this and get:

```
> options(show.error.messages = FALSE)  
> getSymbols("gewg", warnings = FALSE)  
Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'`
```

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT:
I've included the code I used to test it and as can be seen only NOTE1 shows up and NOTE2 doesn't appear. I tried it with a working ticker in a2 and both NOTE1 and NOTE2 shows up.

```
> tester2 <- function(){
+ tester <- function() {
+ a <- getSymbols("GOOG", auto.assign = FALSE)
+ cat("NOTE1")
+ a2 <- getSymbols("JWEGOWN", auto.assign = FALSE)
+ cat("NOTE2")
+ a3 <- getSymbols("GS", auto.assign = FALSE)
+ return(a3)
+ }
+ return(try(tester(), TRUE))
+ }
> af <- tester2()
NOTE1Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
>
```

Comment: The script is only generating warnings, so it should not crash. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to run tests on a list of stocks using loops and every time I run getSymbol() on a stock symbol that yahoo doesn't have data for it will stop the loop and give me this message. Thats why I"m trying to find a way to override it.

Comment: Oh and I turned off error message otherwise there is an error that says something similar to: "Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=gewg&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=11&e=14&f=2011&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=gewg&x=.csv'"

Comment: I would say: accept the errors messages and use try() to catch the errors. (see also my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do this kind of thing is to use `try`. This would look something like (example from the documentation of `try`):

```
 set.seed(123)
 x <- stats::rnorm(50)
 doit <- function(x)
 {
     x <- sample(x, replace=TRUE)
     if(length(unique(x)) > 30) mean(x)
     else stop("too few unique points")
 }
 ## alternative 1
 res <- lapply(1:100, function(i) try(doit(x), TRUE))
```

The result in `res` now shows either a normal output, or an object of class `try-error`. Combining the list can be done using:

```
# Replace the errors by `NULL`
res2 = lapply(res, 
   function(x) 
     if(!inherits(x, "try-error")) 
       return(x) 
     else 
       return(NULL))
resfinal = do.call("c", res2)
```

`resfinal` is now a list with only the results that did not fail.

Comment: I've been looking at using try as well, however I'm not sure if it fits my scenario at the moment since handling empty data is not the problem. 

But instead I need to override the error message so that my loop to fetch data can continue running even if some of them fail.

Comment: try is specifically meant to this: override the error message.

Comment: hmm i tried using try after you mentioned it, but it still stops the loop mid-way. could it be because there is some sort of coding within the function "getSymbols()" that is not responding to the try?

Comment: Without a reproducible example, it is hard for us to exactly determine what is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for the help so far, I've edited the original post to include the code I was referring to.